# get value from url (get method ) using php

Tags: php, html, get

i am getting value from url, URL is like below

```
 http://*****/test.php?register=true$gcm_regid=Amit&name=amit.sid@gmail.com&email=asdxcvxcvxzcvxc
```

and i am printing that value by below code

```
$gcm_regid = $_GET["gcm_regid"];
$name = $_GET["name"]
$email = $_GET["email"]
echo $name; ======>this is line 14-<==========
```

but i am getting error like

```
     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /******/test.php on line 14
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply enough, you're missing semicolons after the `$name` and `$email` lines.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the semicola `;` after `$_GET["name"]` and `$_GET["email]`

```
$gcm_regid = $_GET["gcm_regid"];
$name = $_GET["name"];
$email = $_GET["email"];
echo $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your missing semicolons.
and

```
http://*****/test.php?register=true$gcm_regid=Amit&name=amit.sid@gmail.com&email=asdxcvxcvxzcvxc
```

In this link you are using `$` symbol instead of `&`.
change `$gcm_regid`  to  `&gcm_regid`

Answer (score 0):

Simply, There are two Problems,
1st one, you are missing semicolons,

```
$name = $_GET["name"]
$email = $_GET["email"]
```

& 2nd one, problem is in url passing elements,

```
http://*****/test.php?register=true$gcm_regid=Amit&name=amit.sid@gmail.com&email=asdxcvxcvxzcvxc
```

Change this line to this,

```
http://*****/test.php?register=true&gcm_regid=Amit&name=amit.sid@gmail.com&email=asdxcvxcvxzcvxc
```

The mistake is "true$gcm_regid", it will come as "true&gcm_regid"